# ExtJS rest proxy not send actual request to rails server after get response code 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, extjs, proxy, extjs4

I recently want to implement rails4 API with ExtJS 4.2.2 as front-end framework.

-Rails 4 using REST ==> `http://localhost:3000`

-ExtJS also use rest proxy ==> `http://localhost:1841`

so when request to rails server it will consider cross-domain

It work just well when i use ExtJS rest proxy to retrieve data from rails server , but it strange when i use POST, PUT, or DESTROY method to server, server response code 200(ok) to client, but client didn't re-send actual request again to server after get the respond 200.

server(application controller)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

# For all responses in this controller, return the CORS access control headers.

def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, HEAD'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, content_Type, Accept'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end


def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == "OPTIONS"
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, HEAD'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, content_Type, Accept'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
end
end
```

server (routes):

```
BnDERP::Application.routes.draw do  
   root "public#index"
   get "show/:permalink", :to => 'public#show'
   match "admin", :to => "access#index", via: [:get,:post]
   get  ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
   post  ':controller(/:action(/:id))'

   match '*all' => 'application#cors_preflight_check', :constraints => {:method => 'OPTIONS'}, via: [:options]

  resources :sections
end
```

ExtJS store:

```
Ext.define('ERP.store.Sections', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'ERP.model.Section', 
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {            
        type: 'rest',       
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/sections',      
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'sections',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

server log:

when using GET: server receive OPTIONS method ==> respond code 200(ok) ==> client resend actual request with GET method

```
Started OPTIONS "/sections?_dc=1394515993496&page=1&start=0&limit=25" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 12:33:13 +0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by ApplicationController#cors_preflight_check as */*
  Parameters: {"_dc"=>"1394515993496", "page"=>"1", "start"=>"0", "limit"=>"25", "all"=>"sections"}
  Rendered text template (0.1ms)
Filter chain halted as :cors_preflight_check rendered or redirected
Completed 200 OK in 78ms (Views: 17.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/sections?_dc=1394515993496&page=1&start=0&limit=25" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 12:33:14 +0700
Processing by SectionsController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"_dc"=>"1394515993496", "page"=>"1", "start"=>"0", "limit"=>"25"}
  Section Load (0.0ms)  SELECT A.*,B.name AS Page FROM sections AS A LEFT JOIN pages AS B ON A.page_id=B.id
Completed 200 OK in 112ms (Views: 6.3ms | ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)
```

when using PUT or DESTROY: server receive OPTIONS method ==> respond code 200(ok) ==> client not send actual request

```
Started OPTIONS "/sections/3?_dc=1394516006492" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 12:33:26 +0700
Processing by ApplicationController#cors_preflight_check as */*
  Parameters: {"_dc"=>"1394516006492", "all"=>"sections/3"}
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Filter chain halted as :cors_preflight_check rendered or redirected
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

What going on with these problem? or i missed something else ?

Any help will be appreciate.